Trying to add a contact to a contact group
I have a method that I'm trying to add a contact to my Xero tenant which works. I am then wanting to add it to a group I have made on Xero Called "Trading Group". I don't want to make the contact in my app then go to Xero to add it to the trading group; however, when I try do it with my method it doesn't add the contact to the contact group.
I tried to do it how I thought it would work, but the contact did not end up being added to the contact group.
 public async Task<string> CreateContactAsync(string accessToken, string tenantId, Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Model.Accounting.Contacts contacts)
 {
     var summarizeErrors = true;
     var idempotencyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

     try
     {
         var tradingContactGroupId = Guid.Parse(XeroInformation.TradingAppGroup);

         // Retrieve the existing contact group
         var tradingContactGroup = await _accountingApi.GetContactGroupAsync(accessToken, tenantId, tradingContactGroupId);

         // Create or update the contact
         var result = await _accountingApi.UpdateOrCreateContactsAsync(accessToken, tenantId, contacts, summarizeErrors, idempotencyKey);

         // Ensure the contact list is initialized before adding
         if (tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].Contacts == null)
         {
             tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].Contacts = new List<Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Model.Accounting.Contact>();
         }

         // Add the newly created/updated contact to the contact group
         tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].Contacts.Add(result._Contacts[0]);

         // Create a minimal `ContactGroups` object to pass only the contacts
         var updatedContactGroup = new ContactGroup
         {
             ContactGroupID = tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].ContactGroupID,
             Contacts = tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].Contacts,
             Status = tradingContactGroup._ContactGroups[0].Status

         };

         var contactGroupsToUpdate = new ContactGroups
         {
             _ContactGroups = new List<ContactGroup> { updatedContactGroup }
         };

         var updatedContactGroupResult = await _accountingApi.UpdateContactGroupAsync(accessToken, tenantId, tradingContactGroupId, contactGroupsToUpdate);

         return result._Contacts[0].ContactID.ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         _logger.LogError($"Exception when calling CreateContacts: {e.Message}");
         throw;
     }
 }


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
